# how to creatre dynamic horizontal listview?

Tags: android

how to display listview horizontaly like this image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKk7o.jpg. iwant to display listview imageand text horizontally and load listview dynamically .this example http://www.androidconnect.org/2012/05/10/como-hacer-listview-horizontales/ load single image form all textview and alll textview are hardcoded  no image load parallel for each string all data are static

```
HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setAdapter(new HAdapter());

}

private static String[] dataObjects = new String[]{ "Text #1",
    "Text #2",
    "Text #3",
    "Text android",
    "Text connnect",
    "www.androidconnect.org"};

private class  HAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public HAdapter(){
        super();
    }
    private OnClickListener mOnButtonClicked = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button bt = (Button) v;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hola desde " + bt.getText(),  
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
        }
    };


    public int getCount() {
        return dataObjects.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View retval =    
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
        Button button = (Button) retval.findViewById(R.id.clickbutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(mOnButtonClicked);
        title.setText(dataObjects[position]);

        return retval;
    }

};

}
```

Comment: Why do you need a Horizontal Listview to achieve this? Simple Gallery or View Pager will do the trick.

Comment: Because `Gallery` is deprecated and `ViewPager` does it a page at a time, rather than smooth scrolling?

Comment: but gellllery  take so much space i just show in single image height space and rotate horizontlaly also gallery not display image text.im load image from json file over http